# Как извлечь числа из строки Java?

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка

```
46 55 66 95
```

Нужно ёё переоразовать в масив.
P.S. Числа могут быть любой длинны!

Comment: А как вы уже пробовали и с какими проблемами столкнулись?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коллекции и списки не разбирал еще то вот моё решение:

```
String string = "4666 155 0 -95";
    int count = 1;
    char space = ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == space) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] array = new int[count];
    count = 0;
    int beginNumber = 0;
    int endNumber;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == space) {
            endNumber = i;
            array[count] = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(beginNumber, endNumber));
            count++;
            beginNumber = endNumber + 1;
        } else if (i == string.length() - 1) {
            array[count] = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(beginNumber, string.length()));
        }
    }
    System.out.print("int array: ");
    for (int anArray : array) {
        System.out.print(anArray + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Такое себе решение. Подходит если вообще ничего еще не разбирал :)

Comment: Это реально круто!!!! ))))

Answer (score 4):

**Олдскул**

```
String text = "46 55 66 95";
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String part : text.split("\\s")) {
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
}
```

**StreamAPI (Java 8+)**

```
String text = "46 55 66 95";
int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s"))
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .toArray();
```

Стоит иметь в виду, что если в тексте вдруг окажутся не числовые символы, то `Integer.parseInt()` выбросит NumberFormatException.

Comment: чтобы отсеять не числовые символы можно использовать filter(s -> s.matches("^-?\\d+$"))

Answer (score 2):

Ну используйте, например, `Scanner`

```
String data = "46 55 66 95";
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(data)) {
    while (s.hasNextInt()) {
        int num = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```